# How to split a long list into each column with equal member

Tags: python-3.x

Now, I have a long list of str like this
['aaa','bbb','ccc,'ddd,'eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii',.......] for 300 members

I would like to group into each column with 5 members, the first 5 members go to column1 and the next 5 members go to column2 like this;

column1
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee

column2
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
jjj

Can I coding with pandas dataframe or other package reccommend?
Thx

Comment: What columns are you referring to? Database columns? What database are you using, and what solutions have you already tried. Please provide code sample of a minimum reproducible sample

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the *numpy* library
Example:

```
import numpy as np #importing the library

array = np.array(["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii"])
#creating a numpy array

array = array.reshape(3,3)
#reshape the array into a 3x3 "table"

array = np.swapaxes(array,0,1)
#swapping axis 0 and axis 1 such that "aaa","bbb","ccc" will be a column but not a row
```

The result will be

```
array([['aaa', 'ddd', 'ggg'],
       ['bbb', 'eee', 'hhh'],
       ['ccc', 'fff', 'iii']], dtype='<U3')
```

To convert this array to a pandas DataFrame, simply do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple slice operation would suffice.

```
l=['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii','jjj','kkk','lll'] 
new_list=[l[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(l)-5,5)]
print(new_list) #[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee'], ['fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii', 'jjj']]
```

Let's break this down : Loop from 0th element to last-5th element in steps of 5. Every time slice that part of the array and append it to the new list.
Expanded as a for loop :

```
new_list=[]
for i in range(0,len(l)-5,5):
    new_list.append(l[i:i+5])
```